# Cannot connect IBAction to table view from xib

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, xib, ibaction

I am using this open source framework in swift https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu for my view controller.

I am using xib for the tableview cells and the tableview as shown in the demo projects.

However, when I go to connect my buttons from the tableview cell to the table view controller Xcode will not let me. I am working on the NotificationTableViewCell and NotificationTableVC files.

I have set up the project properly and can get the cell up and running as well as the project itself. However if I can't get the buttons to connect I cannot add the needed functionality.

The demo projects also have this behaviour when I cloned some from the repository. I looked through the issues and no one seemed to mention anything about connecting IBActions to the view, so I did, but I assume there is something I am missing.

I have attached screen shots to help you see my issue. I need to access the cellForRowIndexPath as well.

[image]

[image]

My xib is given the class of my table view cell which still wont allow me to interact with the tableview controller.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I have figured out a working solution. Thanks to Gurtej Singh.

Here is the code:

1) I added this line in the `cellForRowIndexPath`

```
cell.mybutton.addTarget(self, action: "declineRequest:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

2) Now I am able to access the button if I write a function called `declineRequest`

Since I want to delete the cell based on its data I use this function and add the Parse query logic.

```
 func declineRequest(sender: UIButton) {
    var cell: NotificationsTableViewCell = sender.superview!.superview as! NotificationsTableViewCell
     .... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to connect a table view cell element to a table view controller class via IB (and from what I know, it's not correct to do so as well, because there will be multiple cells and re-usability).

Connect the element from the IB to your Cell class (.h/.m), create one if you don't have it , like NotificationTableViewCell.m, and then access the connected element from the delegate methods inside your Table View controller class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gurtej Singh, it looks like you know what your talking about, can you elaborate with a list of steps perhaps since I haven't done this procedure. Can it be done with just a .swift file? Once I make them how does the tableview controller access it? Like when you mention "then access the connected element from the delegate methods inside your Table View controller class".

Comment: Sure, follow these steps, I work in Obj-C, but I am sure similar steps should apply for Swift as well : 1. Create a new Class called NotificationTableViewCell and give it a base class of UITableViewCell. 2. Go into your cell .xib and in the right panel (3rd tab) give it a Class of NotificationTableViewCell. 3. CTRL-Drag your element into your new .m/.h file with both files open, call it closeButton lets say. 4. Access your element   inside the table view controller where you create your cells, method should be cellForRowAtIndexPath, for ex. cell.closeButton. Let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Gurtej, if you look at the screen shots I do have a NotificationTableViewCell Class that I can connect IBActions and Outlets too, are you suggesting to make another one? Just making sure

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I do see a .swift class as well. Connect into that. But make sure you do step 2.

Comment: Yes, I have that in swift already if you look at the first screen shot under cells, I can connect my Outlets fine, i want to be able to connect IBActions for the tableviewcontroller to update the rows depending if they hit the check or x buttons.

Comment: Connect your outlets into the cell class, and don't use IBActions in this case. Find where your cells are getting created (most likely cellForRowAtIndexPath in the table view controller) and add an action programmatically on your button by accessing it there.

Comment: Okay ill try this method, not sure how I can add functionality to the button when its clicked in that cellForRowIndexPath however. Will play around with it.

Comment: Use this : cell.closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside); and definer your buttonAction method inside your Table View Controller class.

Comment: Gurtej Singh when you have time please edit your answer with code for the behavior you just described thanks!

Comment: Gurtej problem with your solution is i need to access my cell for row index path and i cannot add parameters using addTarget

Comment: Yes, you can access the cell from the method like this in Obj-C : UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
Convert this to swift and you should be able to access your cell. Here sender is your button on which you added the target. Hope this helps.

Comment: C'mon dude. Google it :)

Comment: var cell: UITableViewCell = sender.superview!.superview as! UITableViewCell  is what i came up with

Comment: Instead of UITableViewCell, use your custom cell class.

Comment: Yah cool i think i can derive a solution now that i have the cell